# Regex expression for [number2] in [number],[number2][word]

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find a regular expression to find `[number2]` in `[number],[number2][word]`.

So far I've tried with `[,](\d*)`, but it also gets me the comma.

**Demo:** https://regexr.com/59eqa

Comment: Do you have a list of valids and invalids?

Comment: I inadvertently deleted the question, sorry. @FabioPalm it's just like 150 in `4120,150[char]` where both number1 and number2 are integers.

Comment: What if `number` is a word ? What if `word` is a punctuation ? So, what does the _2nd number_ have to do with anything ? It needs more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You may use:

`(?<=,)(\d*)`

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LxyEqQ/1/)

**Detail:**

`(?<=,)`: positive look behind that doesn't consume character but indicate that the number must have `,` before it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the match only, you could use 2 lookarounds, asserting a comma to the left and a char a-zA-Z to the right.

Use `\d+` to match 1 or more digits.

```
(?<=,)\d+(?=[a-zA-Z])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/D6au4R/1/)

If there should be a digit before the comma as well:

```
(?<=\d,)\d+(?=[a-zA-Z])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ralwDv/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers do not handle the case that the second (or two numbers) is matched.
If the second number must be captured, this can be done with
\b\d+,(\d+)[A-Za-z]
where the "number2" is contained in captured group 1.